# Multiple issues with reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

I would like to suggest many things about reputation graph.

1. It does *not* pan. I can zoom in/out perfectly, but I can see my reputation graph for only 2 months. Is there a way to pan the graph left and right?

[image: my reputation graph]

2. I would love to see badges earned on that timeline. It is really easy to add scatter points series to line series using highcharts. You can also add multiple symbols for type of badges earned (such as gold, silver, bronze). So, ultimately you will get a graph with a line series and 3 types of scatter series.
3. It is taking significant amount of loading time. I believe that you are using highcharts for drawing the graph. Is there a way to speed up loading of graph. Is there a reason behind using highcharts, there are a lot of canvas based charting libraries. Those libraries will definitely do it faster for ya. You can also use excanvas if at all you care about internet explorer.